# How do I Backup my genuine Ubuntu Linux and move to windows 10?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, windows, backup, syslinux

How do I Backup my genuine Ubuntu Linux and move to windows 10? I have installed windows many times, but never from Linux to windows, I’ve never used Linux before. Also Dont wanna get into GRUB/partition related issues (that I have heard so much about ), I may want to go back to Linux that's why i need to have a backup for the genuine Linux that is shipped with my laptop (if it comes with keys like windows, i would want to know about it)

Comment: You can reinstall Ubuntu anytime,  no keys or serials required.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed to know, I thought that Ubuntu may also be a paid software like windows . And thankfully the second part of the answer for installing windows 10, There didn't occur any problem while installing the normal way with usb flash drive as a boot device

Answer (score 3):

It does not work like that.

You install an operating system from the installation media that the provider of that operating system hands out.

- For Ubuntu: you download an ISO, burn the ISO and then boot from the ISO.
- For Windows: generally you need to lease a license key. If you have one (you can have one stored in your BIOS; if so Windows picks it up by itself probably) you can legally download Windows from any location (even a location not from Microsoft), burn the ISO, boot from the ISO and insert your key when asked.   If you do not own a license key for -that- system (and yes you need 1 key per installation) you need to lease a license key from a Windows reseller (ie. by buying a copy of Windows you basically lease a license).

Regarding the backup: ONLY personal files are worth backing up. The normal system files you restore by installing a new Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Backing up an unused Ubuntu for possible future use makes no sense. By the time you will eventually need it you are faced with a rusty old distribution that will desperately need to be upgraded anyway (Ubuntu 14.04 is rather dated already).

Installing Ubuntu from scratch is so incredibly fast and easy that many people only backup their data but don't care much about their OS. Only if it was heavily customized you may save some time but this may not be the case here.

More than an Ubuntu backup you may need appropriate drivers for Windows, which may not be included.

In case you feel safer with a backup, here is our list of backup solutions:

- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)